# Chaining methods in a custom class that return objects of a superclass

Tags: ruby, class, object, methods, chaining

I have the following class defination

```
class Map < Array

def find_all_activerecord
  self.find_all { |element| element.class.superclass == ActiveRecord::Base }
end

def find_all_family_nil
  find_all { |element| element.try(:family) == nil }
end

def find_all_parents
  self.find_all_activerecord.find_all_family_nil
end

end
```

I can do the following

```
@map = Map.new
@map.find_all_activerecord
@map.find_all_family_nil
```

But when i try

```
@map.find_all_parents
```

I get an error of undefined method 'find_all_family_nil' on []:Array

I understand what is happening. The custom methods are returning array objects and the method is defined on Class::Map

How does one create custom methods on a custom class, that may return objects of a higher class, and yet be able to chain them

---

another problem I am encountering is 
changing class
if

```
   @map = Map.new
```

then

```
   @map = @map + [1,2,3]

   @map.class # => Array
```

why is this happening what should be done and what area of study is this

Answer (score 3):

As you've probably figured, your `find_all` method is returning an `Array` object when it should be returning a `Map` object.

One fix I can think of is:

```
class Map < Array
  def find_all(&block)
    self.class.new(super(&block))
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Best way to wrap it and make it composable is simply to return a new Map created using the copy constructor you inherit.

Comment: @IlyaO. Can you please elaborate on copy constructor and what does wrapping mean and also look at extension problem of changing class